# Can Twilio's Lookup API tell if a number is connected or not?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I saw that Twilio's Lookup API can tell you whether a phone number is landline, mobile, or voip, as well as what the carrier is. Is there any functionality or possibility of telling whether a number is disconnected or not, similar to what [RealPhoneValidation](https://realphonevalidation.com/resources/phone-number-validator-tool/) does?

For example, I looked up a disconnected phone number in RealPhoneValidation and this was the output, versus the Twilio Lookup API only provided the line type and carrier.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem

By default, Twilio Lookup API does not provide information on phone number’s connection status with provider.

## Solution

Twilio Lookup API allows for “addons”, one of which being the “payfone” addon that uses another service (payfone) to determine phone connection status.

## References

Twilio Lookup API: https://www.twilio.com/docs/lookup/api

Twilio addons: https://www.twilio.com/docs/add-ons

Twilio Payfone addon: https://www.twilio.com/docs/add-ons/quickstart#using-the-payfone-lookups-add-on

Comment: In addition to this add-on, which as far as I can tell does not quite provide the same behavior (it looks like it's more related to TCPA compliance), there is a separate other Twilio Add-on that provides the exact behavior that I'm looking for - https://www.twilio.com/console/add-ons/XB41d31d7c7d90b5456ec9dc5403d08a00

Though I also contacted the RealPhoneValidation company and their price is 1/5 the price of either of these Twilio add-ons.